# spurious >> after image on Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

Ok, the most simple application thinkable. I have a slide and it shall contain nothing else than just an image (in the middle; not covering the entire slide. This shall look like
[image]

Ok, the most simple application thinkable. I have a slide and it shall contain nothing else than just an image (in the middle; not covering the entire slide. This shall look like

enter image description here

Sorry for using this particular image but I had be sure there is no problem with the graphs I produce.

You may notice those two annoying >> below the image on the left?

That's the Latex fragment I have used:

```
\begin{frame}{Position by KIID}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth>]{graphs2/index.png}
\caption{Position by KIID for 2100845}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

and in case you need that...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sparklines}
\usepackage{default}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a stray `>` after `width=.5\textwidth`

Off-topic:

- you don't need `graphicx` with beamer
- are you sure you want to load the `default` package and not the `default` theme? If you want the theme, you don't need it as it is loaded by beamer.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sparklines}
%\usepackage{default}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Position by KIID}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Position by KIID for 2100845}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the error detection by graphicx here isn't that great, I wonder who I can blame for that...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I only know one thing: You are not the one to blame :)

Comment: I don't know what the default package is doing. Most of those packages I am loading are just like dust accumulating in my files. I am certainly not an expert. It's embarrassing though that I have managed not to spot the > in my textwidth...

Answer (score 4):

`graphicx` just uses `\setlength` to store the supplied width here and `\setlength` does essentially no error checking, any spurious text after a valid length is parsed is simply typeset as if it came after the `\setlength`.

It would be possible (see (2)) to redefine it to silently throw away any spurious trailing tokens (latex already has an internal command that does this)  or perhaps better would be to use a version of that command that checked whether spurious tokens were collected, and if so, give an error, see (3)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\zzz
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

1: \setlength\zzz{.5\textwidth>}

\def\setlength#1#2{\@defaultunits#1\glueexpr#2\relax\relax\@nnil}

2: \setlength\zzz{.5\textwidth>}

% \def\remove@to@nnil#1\@nnil{}
\def\zzrelax{\relax}
\def\remove@to@nnilwitherror#1\@nnil{%
\def\zztmp{#1}\ifx\zztmp\zzrelax\else\@latexerr{unexpected \unexpanded{#1}}\@ehc\fi}
\def\@defaultunitswitherror{\afterassignment\remove@to@nnilwitherror}
\def\setlength#1#2{\@defaultunitswitherror#1\glueexpr#2\relax\relax\@nnil}

3: \setlength\zzz{.5\textwidth>}

\end{document}
```

All three set the length, (1) typesets `>`, (2) discards it and (3) produces the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: unexpected >\relax \relax .

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 3 2: \setlength\zzz{.5\textwidth>}

?
```